# How do i compare two data in r

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

```
x <- c(466.0916, 496.7208, 508.8113, 516.8716, 524.9319)

y <- c(281.6531, 306.3963, 452.0596, 597.9728, 775.5842)
```

in plot, for example x is shown in red, y is shown in blue. How is this done?

Comment: what kind of plot do u need?

Comment: @Salman plotting with ggplot2 (scatter plot)

Comment: @Salman What do i need to do for color ?

Comment: forget it, just accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a simple answer but i am not sure what you want

```
x <- c(466.0916, 496.7208, 508.8113, 516.8716, 524.9319)

y <- c(281.6531, 306.3963, 452.0596, 597.9728, 775.5842)


dtY<-data.frame(x=x,y=y)

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(NULL, aes( x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_point(stat="identity",aes(fill = "X"), data =dtY , alpha = 0.5)
p
```